# No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'string | IntensityHK | PresetHK'.ts(7053)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I am using react and typescript and I am getting an error for dynamically setting up a to call something.something.something for example.

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'string | IntensityHK | PresetHK'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'string | IntensityHK | PresetHK'.ts(7053)
```

My code is working and everything but I cant seem to get this error out, need help. The interface

```
export interface HotKeysModel {
  _id: string
  headphoneVolume: IntensityHK
  overallIntensity: IntensityHK
  backIntensity: IntensityHK
  seatIntensity: IntensityHK
  presets: PresetHK
  email: string

}

export interface IntensityHK {
  increase: string
  decrease: string
}

export interface PresetHK {
  nextPreset: string
  previousPreset: string
}
```

The FC component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { type IntensityHK, type PresetHK, type HotKeysModel } from '../../../../models/hot-keys-model'
import { Colours, FontSize } from '../../../../design/brand-book'
import { ShortcutsIcons } from './shortcuts-icons'

interface Props {
  hotKeys: HotKeysModel
  hotKeysType: keyof HotKeysModel
  intensityType: string | keyof IntensityHK | keyof PresetHK
}

export const ShortcutsText: React.FC<Props> = ({ hotKeys, hotKeysType, intensityType }) => {
  const hotKeysList: string[] = hotKeys[hotKeysType][intensityType].split('+') // The problem is here
  console.log(hotKeysList)

  return (
    <div style={textContainerStyle}>
      {(hotKeysList.length > 0) && hotKeysList.map((keys, index) => (
        keys !== '' &&
        <div key={index} style={textStyle(keys)}>
          <ShortcutsIcons shortcutKey={keys} />
          {keys.toUpperCase()
          }
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

const textContainerStyle: React.CSSProperties = {
  height: '30px',
  background: 'transparent',
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'row',
  alignItems: 'center'

}

function textStyle (keys: string): React.CSSProperties {
  return {
    height: '16px',
    borderRadius: '2px',
    background: Colours.BG600,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'IBM',
    fontSize: FontSize.IBMCaption,
    color: Colours.BG0,
    paddingLeft: '4px',
    paddingRight: '4px',
    marginLeft: '6px',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
}
```

hotkeys[hotkeysType][intensityType] which is similar to obj.headphoneVolume.increase. I do not seem to get error up until hotkeys[hotkeysType] then when I add the next parameter [intensityType] I get the above mentioned error. How can I get rid of this error